# Accessible Index Page Configured wrong - How to fix?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I've ran a website I've made through [SiteCheckerPro](https://sitechecker.pro). I'm seeing a 'critical error', but I'm not sure how to fix it. The error is 'URL Vulnerability: Configured wrong'

The report says:

> "URL Vulnerability
>
> Search engines see your https://website.co.uk and
>   https://website.co.uk/index.html (or https://website.co.uk/index.php)
>   as different pages.
>
> If you don't explicitly tell Google which URL is canonical, Google
>   will make the choice for you, or might consider them both of equal
>   weight, which might lead to unwanted behavior."

I understand what it's telling me, I just can't figure out how to fix it.

I've added a canonical tag

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://website.co.uk/" />
```

and I've added a few htaccess rules to redirect www to non-www and http to https

```
#www > non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#http > https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I can't figure out what else I can do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the `htaccess` file fixed the issue.

```
Redirect 301 /index.html https://website.co.uk/
Redirect 301 /index.php https://website.co.uk/
```

The error is no longer shows in the report.

Comment: This certainly is correct, though one of both rules is enough. It is the direct implementation of what is suggested and obviously required. No magic here.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your htaccess,
it Will redirect index.html or index.php

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteRule ^index.php(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301]
```